# mailbox extension yii error

Tags: php, email, yii

Tried to install mailbox yii extension, followed install instructions, but got error. Dont know how to fix. This is link to extension http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/mailbox/

Here is error trace:

```
Alias "mailbox.MailboxModule" is invalid. Make sure it points to an existing PHP file and the file is readable.

Z:\home\localhost\www\Kare2Match\framework\YiiBase.php(316)

304         if($isClass && (class_exists($className,false) || interface_exists($className,false)))
305             return self::$_imports[$alias]=$className;
306 
307         if(($path=self::getPathOfAlias($alias))!==false)
308         {
309             if($isClass)
310             {
311                 if($forceInclude)
312                 {
313                     if(is_file($path.'.php'))
314                         require($path.'.php');
315                     else
316                         throw new CException(Yii::t('yii','Alias "{alias}" is invalid. Make sure it points to an existing PHP file and the file is readable.',array('{alias}'=>$alias)));
317                     self::$_imports[$alias]=$className;
318                 }
319                 else
320                     self::$classMap[$className]=$path.'.php';
321                 return $className;
322             }
323             else  // a directory
324             {
325                 if(self::$_includePaths===null)
326                 {
327                     self::$_includePaths=array_unique(explode(PATH_SEPARATOR,get_include_path()));
328                     if(($pos=array_search('.',self::$_includePaths,true))!==false)

+  Z:\home\localhost\www\Kare2Match\framework\YiiBase.php(196): YiiBase::import("mailbox.MailboxModule", true)

+  Z:\home\localhost\www\Kare2Match\framework\base\CModule.php(282): YiiBase::createComponent("mailbox.MailboxModule", "mailbox", null, array("userClass" => "PersonAbstract", "userIdColumn" => "k2m_internal_id", "usernameColumn" => "nickname"))

+  Z:\home\localhost\www\Kare2Match\framework\web\CWebApplication.php(337): CModule->getModule("mailbox")

+  Z:\home\localhost\www\Kare2Match\framework\web\CWebApplication.php(276): CWebApplication->createController("mailbox")

+  Z:\home\localhost\www\Kare2Match\framework\web\CWebApplication.php(141): CWebApplication->runController("mailbox")
```

Need help with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Just Add 'class' property to module 'mailbox' in /protected/config/main.php as follows:

```
'modules' => array(

   'mailbox'=>
    array(
            'class' => 'application.extensions.mailbox.MailboxModule',
            ..............
            ..............
            'userClass' => 'User',
            'userIdColumn' => 'id',
            'usernameColumn' =>  'username',  

    );
```

If you find this answer is helpful, please vote this one for others to get it easily.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tough one to help on because the solution is actually provided right there in your output: "Make sure it points to an existing PHP file and the file is readable."

So the first thing to check it where is the alias "mailbox.MailboxModule" located and where does it point? Is it to an existing PHP file? If yes, then do the file's permission allow the web server to read it?

To find the alias try a text search through your code. To find the file's permissions go into terminal and do an `ls /path/to/theFile.php` (on Mac or Linux... Windows, I don't know) If you are working over FTP you can often right click on a file and get a context menu to find out more info about a file's permissions.

To understand file permissions [read this.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_permissions)

Comment: I followed the instructions, there was just 4 steps: Unzip to modules directory.
Install data/structure.sql

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution:

I think, you have placed 'mailbox' extension in /protected/extensions/. Please place 'mailbox' extension in '/protected/modules'. it resolves your problem.